# Engine in database design

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an innodb database:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE imdb () ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() 
ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 1
```

What is wrong with the above command, from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database engine can only be specified for table, not database

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html

So when you create database - you don't specify it, and when you create a table - you do.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

PS: on the page you've given the link to it is

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MYISAM;
       ^----- table, not database
```